How to place a colored dot in the center of states in maps::map in R?
I made a map of the U.S. using the  map function in the maps package of R.
library(maps)
map("state")

I would like to add colored dots to the center of select states.
Below is a simple example of my desired outcome (drawn by hand):

Is there a way to draw these centered dots in maps::map?

Figured out a way using map.text and the unicode for a centered circle (i.e., :"U2022"):
map("state")
map.text("state",regions=c("wisconsin","illinois","indiana"),labels = rep("\U2022",3),cex=1.5, col = "red", add=T)
map.text("state",regions=c("minnesota","iowa","missouri"),labels = rep("\U2022",3),cex=1.5, col = "orange", add=T)
map.text("state",regions=c("nebraska","kansas"),labels = rep("\U2022",2),cex=1.5, col = "goldenrod", add=T)



I'd try:
library(ggplot2)
library(usmapdata)

centroid_labels <- usmapdata::centroid_labels("states")
polygons <- usmapdata::us_map(regions = c("states"))

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = centroid_labels, geom = "point", color = "red")+
  #geom_sf_text(data = centroid_labels, aes(label = abbr))+
  geom_sf(data = polygons, fill = "transparent", color = "black")+
  theme_void()


Thanks for the answer. Yes I already know about ggplot's ability to do this. But the purpose of my question was specifically about whether maps also had a way to do this. (Useful for maps already made in maps package)
